# AVAudioPlayer Play audio on music plays on the sound box of phone calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a simple code using AVAudioPlayer, to play a .caf audio:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)playAudio{

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:audiosrc];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];


    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                        error:nil];

    _audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;

    [_audioPlayer play];



}
```

The audio play very well, but he did not run the audio through the speakers of the device , but runs the audio on the speaker where the phone call is made , thus making the audio becomes very low , how to solve and change sound box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the top of your `playAudio` method:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```